# Scaling a G-Group in RN-SVG

Tags: javascript, react-native, scaling, react-native-svg

In my app I procedurally create an SVG with this code:

```
const AnimatedG = Animated.createAnimatedComponent( G )

const transform = 'translate(63.359 83.424)'

const scale = [ 1, 1.04 ] // [ 1, 1 ]
  
return <AnimatedG transform={transform} scale={scale}>
  {circles.map( ( c, ix ) => <Circle key={ix} {...c}/> )}
</AnimatedG>
```

Here the scaling applies rather on `translate` coords, than on the G's size itself, and the the group is shifted downwards by 4% instead of stretching itself vertically.

[image]

What is the proper way of resizing the G? What am I missing?